# Is there a way suspend 12.04 using a bash command while keeping the password prompt?

Tags: 12.04, bash, suspend, sleep

I desire to suspend my Ubuntu 12.04 install with a bash script. The `pm-suspend` command will not prompt for a password when resumed. Is there a way to suspend my machine and have a password prompt when resumed via a bash command?

Answer (score 1):

Lock the screen before suspending.

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l && pm-suspend
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have it set to ask for a password after suspend in System Settings > Brightness and Lock?

Answer (score 0):

The screen locking mechanism works from the user who is logged into the Unity session. The `pm-suspend` command need to be run as root. I simply need to have more privileges set regarding the `pm-suspend` command.

Comment: Then run the `gnome-screensaver-command -l && sudo pm-suspend`. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers on how to allow your user to run pm-suspend as root (with sudo), without requiring you to enter your password.